# boost::program_options::positional_options_description termination

Tags: c++, boost, abort, boost-program-options

The following program aborts with *`pointer being freed was not allocated`*:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::program_options::positional_options_description positional;
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled and linked the program with Boost 1.46.1, which I built myself into /usr/local, on OS X 10.6.7. I can't find any installed libboost_program_options other than the one I'm (supposedly) linking against.

Any idea what causes this crash?

---

**Edit**: As for stacktrace, the program

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <execinfo.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::program_options::positional_options_description positional;
    void* callstack[128];
    int i, frames = backtrace(callstack, 128);
    char** strs = backtrace_symbols(callstack, frames);
    for (i = 0; i < frames; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", strs[i]);
    }
    free(strs);
    return 0;
}
```

built as

```
g++ -Wp,-MMD,.make-debug/main.dd -Wall -g3 -I/usr/local/include -c main.cc -o .make-debug/main.o
g++ -o sandbox .make-debug/main.o -lboost_program_options -L/usr/local/lib
```

and run as ./sandbox produces the output

```
0   sandbox                             0x00000001000017bf main + 57
1   sandbox                             0x0000000100001764 start + 52
2   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
sandbox(50587) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff70506500: pointer being freed was not al
located
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Command terminated
```

As for building Boost:

```
$ cd boost_1_46_1
$ ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
$ ./bjam toolset=darwin-4.2
```

And here's my ~/user-config.jam:

```
using darwin : 4.0 : g++-4.0 ;
using darwin : 4.2 : g++-4.2 ;
using darwin : 4.5.1 : /Users/matan/usr/bin/g++ ;
```

Comment: Any chance you could post the stack?

Comment: also try installing from something like mac ports instead of building boost yourself

Comment: I've only used up to 1.44, but don't have this problem.

Comment: See my answer for my latest update. I'm not happy with it because I really want the latest gcc, to get it's C++0x features. So I'm still on the lookout for a proper solution to get the two girls working together.

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to reproduce

```
macmini:stackoverflow samm$ cat po.cc
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << std::endl;
    boost::program_options::positional_options_description positional;
    return 0;
}
macmini:stackoverflow samm$ g++ -I /opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_program_options po.cc
macmini:stackoverflow samm$ ./a.out
1_46_1
macmini:stackoverflow samm$
```

you should update your question with the steps you used to build boost, particularly the arguments to bjam.

Comment: Updated my question with further details.

Answer (score 1):

I think I resolved the issue, but I'm not happy with my solution. I neglected to mention that I previously installed gcc 4.6.0 with --program-suffix=-4.6 in /usr/local. Uninstalling it and rebuilding Boost solved the issue. I then had no compilers installed other than gcc-4.0 and gcc-4.2 which came with XCode. Presumably gcc-4.6 files interfered with gcc-4.0 files or the darwin toolset.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue with g++-mp-4.7 and boost 1.52 on Mac OS X. Did you find a better solution?

Comment: I had the same issue when I upgraded GCC from 4.8.2 to 4.8.3, rebuilding boost with the new compiler made the error disappear.